# Laravel translate values required_if does not work

Tags: laravel, validation, translate, required

I am using Laravel version 5.7 and I want to translate the `value` of `required_if`. I used below action but it does not work. what shall I do?

in RequestObject.php:

```
public function rules() {
 $fee = ''; 
 if ($this['params.fee_status'] == 'pay') { 
     $fee = 'required_if:params.fee_status,pay|numeric|min:100';
 } 
 return [ 'params.fee' => $fee,];
}
```

in resources/lang/en/validation.php :

```
'values' => [
        'params.fee_status' => [
            'pay' => 'default'
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Can you provide code from your request?

Comment: `public function rules()
    { $fee = '';
            if ($this['params.fee_status'] == 'pay') {
                $fee = 'required_if:params.fee_status,pay|numeric|min:100';
            } return [ 'params.fee' => $fee,];}`

Comment: You should need in `validation.php` something like this: `'required_if' => 'The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.',`

Comment: I had this one but it did not work